# Are these statements concerning formal languages true or false, and why?

Tags: formal-languages

Please answer the following question and give me the reasoning.

Are the following statements true or false? If a statement is false, give a counterexample.

1. $uv=vu$ for all strings $u ≠ λ$ and $v ≠ λ$ over an alphabet $Σ={A,B}$.
2. $|L_1L_2|=|L_1| × |L_2|$ for all languages $L_1$ and $L_2$ over the alphabet $Σ={A,B}$. For example, if $L_1$ has 3 strings and $L_2$ has 4 strings, then the concatenation $L_1L_2$ always has $3 × 4 = 12$ strings.

Comment: I removed two tags. "formal languages" on their own are not directly related to computer science, and certainly not to computer assisted proof.

Answer (score 2):

1. Take the words $u:=$"$A$" and $v:=$"$B$". Are the words "$AB"$ and "$BA$" the *same*? No.
2. Well, indeed, we have a canonical map $L_1\times L_2\to L_1L_2$:
   $$\langle u,v\rangle\ \mapsto\ uv$$
   but this *doesn't need to be bijection* if $L_1,\ L_2$ can be any subset of words, as in the following example:

> $L_1:=\{$"$A$","$AA$"$\}$ 
>   $L_2:=\{$"", "$A$"$\}$.
>   
>   Here the string "$AA$" *arises twice* in $L_1L_2$, and we have $L_1L_2=\{$"$A$", "$AA$", "$AAA$"$\}$ so that 
>   $$|L_1L_2|=3\ \ne\ |L_1|\times|L_2|=4\,.$$

Comment: that means two answer  is false, can u explain how u get |L1| ×  |L2|=4

Comment: Yes, we have $|L_1|=|L_2|=2$ and $|L_1\times L_2|=|L_1|\,\cdot\, |L_2|$, finally $2\cdot 2=4$.